# gremlin module not found

Tags: python, joern

I followed the instructions at:

http://joern.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

to install joern, and then the following to test Joern:

http://joern.readthedocs.io/en/latest/access.html

And got this error (using ipython):

```
 import joern.all 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-903145a12480> in <module>()
----> 1 import joern.all

/home/xxxx/Downloads/python-joern-0.3.1/joern/all.py in <module>()
      1 from py2neo import Graph
----> 2 from py2neo.ext.gremlin import Gremlin
      3 import os
      4 
      5 DEFAULT_GRAPHDB_URL = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/"

ImportError: No module named gremlin
```

Can someone teach me how to install "Gremlin"?

I did the following and it is still not working:

```
## wget -O neo4j-gremlin.zip http://mlsec.org/joern/lib/neo4j-gremlin-plugin-2.1-SNAPSHOT-server-plugin.zip 
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/neo4j/plugins/gremlin-plugin
sudo unzip neo4j-gremlin.zip -d /usr/share/neo4j/plugins/gremlin-plugin
```

and the "0.1.tar.gz" have installed the py2neo-gremlin-0.1 as well.

And "pip install Gremlin" does not worked too.

Now I have run out of idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have a version of py2neo installed that is incompatible with Joern. If you used pip to install py2neo, you will get v3.x but Joern appears to only support v2.0 at the moment. Run the following command to confirm:

`python -c "import py2neo; print py2neo.__version__"`

If the above does not print `2.0`, remove *py2neo* by running `pip uninstall py2neo` and then install v2.0 specifically by running `pip install py2neo==2.0`. Then re-test by running `python -c "from py2neo.ext.gremlin import Gremlin"` - it should complete without errors.